# objective-c beginner: getter setter prob and EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, getter-setter, accessor

Iam getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS all the time and I cannot figure out why...

Simple task:

The Parser Class pases XML with touchXML in an NSMutableArray called listArray.
In the Method grabCountry I can access the listArray and listArray.count works well.

Now I need the listArray.count in another Class the MasterViewController.
But Im getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error all the time.
Please help!

Here is the code snipplet:
Parser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Parser : NSObject

@property (strong, retain) NSMutableArray *listArray;
@property (strong, retain) NSURL *url;

-(void) grabCountry:(NSString *)xmlPath;
@end
```

Parser.m

```
#import "Parser.h"
#import "TouchXML.h"

@implementation Parser
@synthesize listArray;
@synthesize url;

-(void) grabCountry:(NSString *)xmlPath {

    // Initialize the List MutableArray that we declared in the header
    listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

    // Convert the supplied URL string into a usable URL object
    url = [NSURL URLWithString: xmlPath];

   //XML stuff deleted

    // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.
   [listArray addObject:[xmlItem copy]];

  //works fine
  NSLog(@"Amount: %i",listArray.count);
}

 @end
```

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TouchXML.h"
#import "Parser.h"

@class Parser;

    @interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController{

    Parser *theParser;

}
@end
```

MasterViewControlelr.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *xmlPath = @"http://url/to/xml.xml";

theParser = [[Parser alloc] init];
//Starts the parser
[theParser grabCountry:xmlPath];

//Here I want to access the Array count, but getting an BAD ACCESS error
NSLog(@"Amount %@",[theParser.listArray count]);

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Can anyone explain me what the problem here is?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, each `@property` has a corresponding instance variable.

In your `-grabCountry` method, you are directly accessing the instance variable in the statement `listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` (same with `url = [NSURL URLWithString: xmlPath];`), instead of the `@property`'s setter method, causing the `NSMutableArray` that you `alloc-init`'d to not be retained by the property. To invoke the `@property`'s setter method, you should call

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.listArray = temp; // or [self setListArray:temp];
[temp release];
```

If you want to have Xcode show an error when you are directly accessing the instance variable of an `@property`, you can have `@synthesize listArray = _listArray`, which changes the name of the instance variable to `_listArray`.

Generally, if there is an `alloc-init`, there must be a corresponding `release` (except if using Automatic Reference Counting).

---

Also, in the `[listArray addObject:[xmlItem copy]];` statement, the call to `copy` is not needed, as `NSArray`s retain every object that is added to them. Calling `copy` also increases the retain count, which is another leak. Instead, you should just have `[self.listArray addObject:xmlItem];`

---

You are getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS because in `NSLog(@"Amount %@",[theParser.listArray count]);`, you are using `%@` format specifier, which is for `NSString`s. You want to print the array's count, an integer, so you should be using `%d` or `%i`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed everything and it sounds plausible to me :) But Im getting the same error when Iam trying to access it: [theParser.listArray count] (from the MasterViewController class)

Comment: Finally caught the problem... You are using `%@` when printing the count (an integer), when you should be using `%d` or `%i`. I also usually get caught by that. =) I have edited my answer to reflect this.